# What is the logic of this fractal?

Tags: c++, logic

I am doing a project for school and need to roughly reproduce this fractal (in BGI):

[image]

I'm stuck trying to find a placement logic for the middle-sized triangles, as they have to be drawn into a for/while loop.
 (I've drawn the main triangle and a circle  on the each side of it.)

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Given the few random points on the left side, it looks vaguely based on an Iterated Function System

Comment: It looks like the coefficients are slightly wrong, since it _almost_ has a D3 symmetry.

Comment: Unless someone finds a general way to reverse-engineer fractals like this one, I'm afraid this question is _too localised_.

Comment: The result doesn't have to look exactly like this (I've placed the big circles exactly in the middle of the triangle sides).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely an IFS. IFS fractals use recursion.. It's like a tree structure, where each branch can have side branches and these can yet again have smaller side branches of their own. In (C-like) pseudocode it would look something like:

```
draw_triangle(vector2d pos, float scale, int depth)
{
  if (depth < MAX_DEPTH) return;

  /* actual graphics code for the triangle goes here.. use pos and scale */

  /* compute center positions for circles side1_pos, side2_pos, etc... */

  draw_circle(side1_pos, 0.5*scale, depth+1);
  draw_circle(side2_pos, 0.5*scale, depth+1);
  draw_circle(side3_pos, 0.5*scale, depth+1);
}

draw_circle(vector2d pos, float scale, int depth)
{
  if (depth < MAX_DEPTH) return;
  /* actual graphics code for the circle goes here.. use pos and scale */

  /* compute center positions for triangles side1_pos, side2_pos, etc... */

  draw_triangle(side1_pos, 0.5*scale, depth+1);
  draw_triangle(side2_pos, 0.5*scale, depth+1);
  draw_triangle(side3_pos, 0.5*scale, depth+1);
}
```